# mysql datetime how can get the data group by interval day, week, month

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, indexing, group-by

when using mysql datetime data type how can get the data group by interval day, week, month in an optimum way. ***if converting the datetime by function it makes index dose not work.***

I want to get number of visitors in every single day.
And also wanna get total sum(visitors) every week for some weeks.
And monthly data want too.

1.My table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS visitip (
                id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                ip VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                totalvisit INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                lastvisit DATETIME NOT NULL,
                country VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                countrycode CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
                city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (id),
                UNIQUE INDEX ipindex2 (ip),
                INDEX ccodeidx (countrycode),
                INDEX lastvisitidx (lastvisit)
```

2.I can get today's visitors with this query

```
SELECT * FROM visitip WHERE lastvisit >= CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 00:00:00')
```

3.how can i get last 7 days each?

4.how can i get last some weeks each?

5.how can i get last some months each?

Answer (score 0):

2. for today's visitors 
   SELECT * FROM visitip WHERE DATE(lastvisit) = DATE(NOW());

3.FOR get last 7 days
SELECT * FROM visitip WHERE DATE(lastvisit) > DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY));

4. SELECT * FROM visitip WHERE DATE(lastvisit) > DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY));

5.
SELECT MONTH(lastvisit), KAYIT_TARIH_SAAT  FROM visitip WHERE YEAR(lastvisit) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(lastvisit) = MONTH(NOW());

or

SELECT * FROM visitip WHERE DATE_FORMAT(lastvisit, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m')